# how to implement auth with multiple request with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jwt

I can get login and when I refresh the browser , login is unauth .

I have been tried to get userinfo , when I refresh the browser , I lost second api data

```
    axios
     .get("http://AGCorp-WS19:4000/global/WindowsAuth",
     {
      params: userData
     })
  .then(res => {
  if (res.data.authrization === "authorized") {
    const { token } = res.data;
    localStorage.setItem("jwt", token);
    setAuthToken(token);
    // Decode token to get user data
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    // Set current user
    console.log(decoded);
    dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
    return axios
      .get(" http://agcorp-ws19:4000/hr/tblEmployee", {
        params: { strOfficeEmail: userData.username }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res.data);
        dispatch({
          type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
          payload: res.data
        });
      });
  } else {
    console.log(res.data);
  }
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
};

// Set logged in user

  export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {

return {

type: GET_USER_EMAIL,

 payload: decoded


   };
  };
   index.js

   if (localStorage.jwt) {

   setAuthToken(localStorage.jwt);

   const decoded = jwt_decode(localStorage.jwt);

   store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));

   }
```

when I submit ,username and password I got `{token: 'asdfasd", authorized:"auth"}` and then the username will go to the second api and give me amount of data .

For example,  UserInformation . I got the first data , but when I refresh , I lost userinformation and the login is unauth.

Comment: Please fix the code to show correctly. Also, please add the reducer you're using

Comment: export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_USER_EMAIL:
      return { ...state, isAuthenticated: true, userEmail: action.payload };
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: !isEmpty(action.payload),
        user: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

Comment: @Poran edit question rather then add it in comment. It looks messy. What about middleware like redux-thunk or redux-observable? What are you using?

Comment: I got two data first time , but when I refresh i lost my second data .